# How do you know if a zeromq message via router .send actually made it?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I have a router socket sending messages to a dealer. Is there a way to find out if the message made it there successfully without passing the message back again and temporarily storing in cache on the router?

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple way. There are more complicated ways like lazy pirate pattern, you can read more on the zeromq guide:

http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc89